# Missing "Web Inspector" Settings in simulator

Tags: safari, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

After doing a "Reset All Content And Settings.." on the simulator the setting to enable using the web inspector in safari has disappeared, and I have no idea how to get it back:

[image: Advanced Settings Menu]

Does anyone have an idea how to get this back, and "remote" debug a webpage in the simulator again?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that this option is not available in the simulated devices. Tip: If you want to connect the console from your desktop Safari, you will need the Technology Preview. the normal one does not discover the simulator (though it finds the real device normally)

Comment: For anybody like me who didn't understand the answer at first, here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Answer (score 13):

i needed to restart desktop safari. might help.

Comment: Apple system has some weird bugs and this is one of them.

Comment: same here, after googling through half the internet, the old "have you tried turning it off and on again" did the trick.

Comment: restarting desktop safari worked for me. it now showed up even though the option is not available to turn on in the simulator

Answer (score 12):

In my case (macOS 10.14.3 and iOS 12.1 simulators), the setting isn't there, but is active by default. Open the simulator and you should see it in Safari under Develop.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that it is enabled by default. Do nothing and it appear in safari developer list

Comment: This requires Safari Technology Preview - will not work on normal Safari

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me download new Safari:
IOS Simulator: 13.4
(Safari Technology Preview)

https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

[Safari Technology Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4RP.png)

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).